# Accessing session variable in JADE

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, pug

My `GET /new` end point looks like this:

```
router.get('/new', function(req, res) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.session.application)); //<-- This prints FINE

  res.render('new', { 
    title: 'Add a new intent'
  });
});
```

And, the `new.jade` file to be rendered looks like:

```
...
h1 #{application.name}
...
```

When I print the `req.session.application` object on the console, it prints fine, but when the `new.jade` is rendered, it does not find the `application` object from the session and thinks it is `null`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Provide variable to template

```
res.render('new', { 
  // <- here is all variables that will be available in jade
  title: 'Add a new intent',
  application: req.session.application
});
```

Comment: But, what if I directly want to access session variables from jade rather than creating a local variable?

Comment: ``res.render('new', {session: req.session});``

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a quick midleware function that checks if the `application` object exists in the session and adds that to the session object like below. With this change, I don't need to pass the `req.session.application` object to the `res.render()` method while rendering a Jade view.

**Middleware in app.js:**

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

  if (req.session && req.session.application) {
    mongoose.model('Application').findOne({ _id: req.session.application._id }, function(err, application) {
      if (application) {
        req.application = application;
        req.session.application = application;  //refresh the session value
        res.locals.application = application;
      }
      // finishing processing the middleware and run the route
      next();
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

**Snippet from Jade view:**

```
...
h1 #{application.name}
...
```